# I am struggling with writing an if/then question for an opportunity

Tags: custom-field

I inserted one new field:

Is there a customer Impending event?

If yes, I need to follow that with mandatory questions.

What is the start date? (answer can be n/a)

What is the end date? (answer can be n/a)

Comment: Is this a coding problem? Can you be more specific as to exactly what you are looking to do? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SF.SE @LHPoirier. It always helps to provide a bit more context when you ask a question such as yours, thus I suspect the reason for the downvotes. You may want to take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting in the future.

It sounds from your question as though you're doing a Visual Flow Interview of some kind. Because of there being a "N/A", it would be the same as asking a "Yes - No" and you'd continue as though there were no alternative branch. In essence, there is no "Else" clause to what you're doing other than to ccontinue.

What you describe is more like the following...

> **Question:** Is there a customer Impending event?
>
> "Yes" Branch:
>
> - If there's a Start Date, enter the value, else continue.
> - If there's an End Date, enter the value, else continue.
>
> "No" Branch:
>
> - Continue